# OR Tools VRPTW Example - initial solution

Tags: or-tools

I am working with example provided by Google's OR Tools - VRPTW and I want to get initial solution, based on some constraints and first solution strategy. Is it true that the initial solution is the first solution the example returns? Also I have second question related to solutions count. When I try to set solution limit like this

```
search_parameters.solution_limit = 5
```

the example still prints just one solution in terminal. Is there something else I need to set to have more solutions returned?

I want to use OR Tools just to find the initial solution - I don't care of optimal solution now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search in the routing library is decomposed into 2 phases:

- Initial solution heuristics
- Local search based improvements

The first one is controlled by the first solution parameter.
It can be omitted if you provide a valid first solution.

The second one is controlled by the choice of the neighborhoods and the meta heuristics. By default, I believe it is a greedy descent that may fail to find improving solution depending on the nature of your problem.

A good setup is to use guided local search with a time limit (as guided local search does not terminate by default). You can try it on you case.

Therefore you should:

- check that local search is enabled
- enable guided local search
- add a time limit

Comment: Ok, thank you. And can you please tell me why the example gives me only one solution even it has plenty of time and solution limit set to 5?

Comment: have you read my answer ?

Comment: Yes, I did. But didn't understood it fully. You meant it like if I enable the two things you suggested and add time limit, than there will be more solutions, because solver will search for solutions until the time limit is reached?

Comment: The solver will only show improving solutions. If the first one it shows is optimal or too hard to improve, it will only show one, independently of time limit. The use of gls can help in the hard to find case.